# StatusArea display of message with hyperlink

Tags: document-creation, hyperlink

just trying to label a hyperlink,  using an example right from the documentation....

```
StatusArea[
 Hyperlink["Wolfram Research, Inc.", "http://www.wolfram.com"],
 "Makers of Mathematica"]
```

This should display "Makers of Mathematica" in the status area,  but displays the URL instead.

Am I missing something here...?   I'm using Mathematica 9 on a Mac.

Tom

Comment: Same on v8 linux, misleading documentation or bug?

Comment: I don't want to say "bug",  but it certainly works as advertised with anything else,  I think the behavior of hyperlink is overriding the functionality of StatusArea.  Oh well... I used "Labeled"  instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my documentation (*Mathematica* 9.0.1, Linux) I found

```
Hyperlink[StatusArea[Framed["Wolfram"], "Makers of Mathematica"], "http://www.wolfram.com"]
```

It works fine!

Comment: Works fine on OSX with 8.0.4 too. +1

Comment: Thanks,  much appreciated!    That helps a lot!